# Custom DatabaseSessionHandler in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to make a custom `DatabaseSessionHandler` but it doesn't work as expected.
The idea is to make the table `sessions` polymorphic to allow the session from multiple models.
*(To be honest, I'm not even sure it's possible)*
But even before changing the table to be polymorphic, I'm trying to add a custom driver in order to manipulate the sessions.
The issue seems that my `DatabaseSessionHandler`, is not correctly called when I try to sign in.

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web'    => [
        'driver'   => 'custom-session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'screen' => [
        'driver'   => 'custom-session',
        'provider' => 'screens',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users'   => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => Domain\User\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'screens' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => Domain\Screen\Models\Screen::class,
    ],
]
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
   //This is how the session is normally registered: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php#L83
    Session::resolved(function ($session) {
        $session->extend('screen-session', function ($app) {
            $table = $app['config']['session.table'];
            $lifetime = $app['config']['session.lifetime'];
            $connection = $app['db']->connection($app['config']['session.connection']);
            return new \Support\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler($connection, $table, $lifetime, $app);
        });
    });

    // This is how the driver "session" is normally registered: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L121
    Auth::resolved(function ($auth) {
        $auth->extend('custom-session', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
            $provider = Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']);

            $guard = new SessionGuard($name, $provider, $app->session->driver('screen-session'));

            if (method_exists($guard, 'setCookieJar')) {
                $guard->setCookieJar($this->app['cookie']);
            }

            if (method_exists($guard, 'setDispatcher')) {
                $guard->setDispatcher($this->app['events']);
            }

            if (method_exists($guard, 'setRequest')) {
                $guard->setRequest($this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest'));
            }
            return $guard;
        });
    });

}
```

**DatabaseSessionHandler.php**
*This is currently a **copy/past** of the existing one that is used by `session` except the namespace. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php*

---

I don't have any error message.

When I try to sign in (`auth()->guard('web')->login($user)`)

- It validate the login
- I know it uses my `DatabaseSessionHandler` to destroy the current
  session in the table.
- The session ID is regenerated and I'm **not** logged in

An another scenario;

- I try to sign in with the "*remember me*"
- It validate the login
- Somehow, the session is updated in the database with the current `user_id` but it doesn't seems that my `DatabaseSessionHandler` have been used
- I'm logged in

Removing the `screen` from the guards and `providers` to only keep `web` and `users`, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it. As always, it's a simple mistake.

I add to change in **.env** file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=screen-session
```

And now it's working as expected.

---

Now, also to answer my another question

> The idea is to make the table sessions polymorphic to allow the session from multiple models. *(To be honest, I'm not even sure it's possible)*

From my quick tests it looks realizable. Here's what I did;

**create_sessions_table.php**

```
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id')->primary();
    $table->nullableMorphs('authenticable');
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
});
```

**DatabaseSessionHandler.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler as BaseDatabaseSessionHandler;

class DatabaseSessionHandler extends BaseDatabaseSessionHandler
{

    /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user's type.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function userType()
    {
        $user = $this->container->make(Guard::class)->user();
        return optional($user)->getMorphClass();
    }

    /**
     * Add the user information to the session payload.
     *
     * @param array $payload
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function addUserInformation(&$payload)
    {
        if ($this->container->bound(Guard::class)) {
            $payload['authenticable_id'] = $this->userId();
            $payload['authenticable_type'] = $this->userType();
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

*Note: If you're using Laravel jetstream, you will probably need a custom `LogoutOtherBrowserSessionsForm` livewire/inertiajs component since this one is based and hardcoded with the `database` session and looks for `user_id` column*